# Minimizing a linear function over the probability simplex

Tags: convex-optimization

I am trying to derive the solution of the problem below but am having trouble

[image]

This is my solution

$L = c^Tx + v(1^Tx - 1) - \lambda^Tx \\
\ \ \ = (c + v1 - \lambda)^Tx - v $

The dual is thus

$\min v \\
st. v1 = \lambda - c \\ \lambda \ge 0$

I dont know how to arrive at theirs. I also don't understand my solution. I have seen the solution from boyd's book on convex optimization but I want to do it through the dual for practice.

Comment: First of all, yours should be $\text{maximize}~{-v}$, not $\text{minimize}~v$. Second, we can eliminate $\lambda$ by noting that $v\vec{1}=\lambda -c$ is identical to $v\vec{1}\succeq -c$. Finally, choose $y=-v$ and you're basically done.

Comment: No, because one is a minimization and one is a maximization. They may be equivalent but they are not the same. And you don't get equal primal and dual objective values if you flip the objective direction like that.

Comment: @MichaelGrant thank you very much. i learnt in class to minimize the negative of the dual (to make the objective function positive). I need to read up more.

Comment: That's a different matter. Many algorithms are designed _only_ for minimization—which means that if you want to maximize something, you have to minimize its negative instead. But when _talking_ about optimization problems you're really not free to flip the sense of the optimization problem like that.

Comment: @MichaelGrant And thank you, I see it now (if I vizualize on a 2D plot) that my dual value will not be the same as the primal one if I flip the point across the x-axis